# FilterIterator should be instance of PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuiteIterator

Tags: phpunit, code-coverage, xdebug

When I activate Xdebug and run a PHPUnit unittest this error occurs: ❌

```
Warning: assert(): assert($iterator instanceof FilterIterator) failed in [...]/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/Filter/Factory.php on line 57
[... some stack trace information ...]
Return value of PHPUnit\Runner\Filter\Factory::factory() must be an instance of FilterIterator, instance of PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuiteIterator returned
```

I'm using

```
PHPUnit 9.5.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Runtime: PHP 7.4.21 with Xdebug 2.8.0
```

The PHPUnit execution call (clued together with PhpStorm) looks like:

```
/usr/bin/php74.bin.cli 
-dzend_extension=/usr/local/php74/lib/php/extensions/xdebug.so 
-dxdebug.collect_params=5 
-dxdebug.profiler_enable=on 
-dxdebug.auto_trace=1 -dxdebug.trace_format=1 
-dxdebug.collect_return=1 -ddisplay_errors=1 
-ddisplay_startup_errors=1 -derror_reporting=E_ALL 
-dmemory_limit=512M 
[...]/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit 
--coverage-filter [...]/src/ 
--bootstrap [...]/utils/unittest/bootstrap.php 
--configuration [...]/utils/unittest/phpunit.xml 
--filter "/(BasicsTest::testReturnBytes)( .*)?$/" 
--test-suffix BasicsTest.php [...]/utils/unittest/basics --teamcity
```

Calling a simple php script with Xdebug activated works well. ✔️

```
/usr/bin/php74.bin.cli 
-dzend_extension=/usr/local/php74/lib/php/extensions/xdebug.so 
-dxdebug.collect_params=5 
-dxdebug.profiler_enable=on -dxdebug.auto_trace=1 
-dxdebug.trace_format=1 -dxdebug.collect_return=1 
-ddisplay_errors=1 -ddisplay_startup_errors=1 
-derror_reporting=E_ALL -dmemory_limit=512M ./test.php
```

Calling the unittests without Xdebug activated works well. ✔️

```
/usr/bin/php74.bin.cli 
-dallow_url_fopen=1 
[...]/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit 
--no-coverage 
--bootstrap [...]/utils/unittest/bootstrap.php 
--configuration [...]/utils/unittest/phpunit.xml 
--filter "/(BasicsTest::testReturnBytes)( .*)?$/" 
--test-suffix BasicsTest.php [...]/utils/unittest/basics --teamcity
```

My phpunit.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/9.5/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="bootstrap.php"
         colors="true"
         verbose="true">
  <coverage>
    <include>
      <directory suffix=".php">../../../src/*</directory>
      <directory suffix=".php">../../../some other dirs/*</directory>
    </include>
    <exclude>
        <directory suffix=".php">../../../some other dirs/*</directory>
    </exclude>
    <report>
        <html outputDirectory="./x_testresults" lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70"/>
    </report>
  </coverage>
  <php>
    <ini name="allow_url_fopen" value="On"/>
    <ini name="memory_limit" value="5G"/>
    <ini name="include_path" value="."/>
  </php>
</phpunit>
```

The unittest

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

class BasicsTest extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    function testReturnBytes(): void {
        $this->assertSame(1, 1);
    }
}
```

The docs say in https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/code-coverage-analysis.html#including-files that

> It is mandatory to configure a filter for telling PHPUnit which source code files to include in the code coverage report. This can either be done using the --coverage-filter command line option or via the configuration file (see The  Element).

This is what I did, see above. Also without setting a `--coverage-filter` parameter PHPUnit complains about missing filter information, so I added it.

For me it feels like the issue is related to the `--coverage-filter` parameter. The error message (see first code paragraph) says `FilterIterator` should be instance of `PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuiteIterator` but I don't know where to adjust this.

Comment: this looks puzzling. on first glance I would perhaps re-init phpunit (move your config away and let phpunit init create a new one), just for quick testing purposes. Then I would swap the configuration files again and run with xdebug 3.

Comment: and do you really have `*` in the XML? It looks like it breaks the syntax highlighting here on SO but I also think its not needed.

Comment: @hakre I did already use different configs, no positive result. The * is there. Will try without it.

Comment: @hakre no change without the * in the XML.

Comment: Can you double-check xdebug 2 (which is EOL) has still support for code-coverage in and is fully compatible with phpunit 9.5? Not that at the end it is just an incompatibility.

Comment: and for xdebug 2 where is the coverage enabled? xdebug.coverage_enable=0 or xdebug.coverage_enable=1 , what are you using?

Comment: @hakre thank you very much for your help. Actually It seems that the include/exclude settings do matter and when I add a suite and call it, it seems to work! So it seems to be related to the context of the test or how a test is grouped and called. Anyway the connection of the problem to Xdebug is still strange. Will dig further.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234929/discussion-between-powtac-and-hakre).

Answer (score 0):

I found some mistakes in my setup and I found a kind of workaround to get the tests to be running with Xdebug.

The mistakes:

- the includes and excludes tags in the phpunit.xml had wrong relative paths
- the settings "-dxdebug.auto_trace=1" for xdebug on the command line command were outdated, [see docs](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide). Actually its strange that the test.php did run well.

The workaround:

- set a testsuite to "." in the phpunit.xml and call it via --testsuite default
- set a "@group dummy" to the specific class I want to test and call it via --group dummy to just call that test.

The testsuite setting in phpunit.xml in detail:

```xml
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="default">
        <directory>./</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

The commandline call now:

```
/usr/bin/php74.bin.cli 
-dzend_extension=/usr/local/php74/lib/php/extensions/xdebug.so 
-dxdebug.collect_params=5 
-dxdebug.profiler_enable=on 
-dxdebug.trace_format=1 
-dxdebug.collect_return=1 
../../vendor/bin/phpunit 
--group no-db 
--verbose 
--debug 
--testsuite default 
--group dummy
```

Comment: *"the settings "-dxdebug.auto_trace=1" for xdebug on the command line command were outdated, see docs."* **Why outdated?** As per your info (`Runtime: PHP 7.4.21 with Xdebug 2.8.0`) that option is valid for Xdebug v2; the "see docs" link is for Xdebug v3.

Comment: @lazyone good point. Need to revisit that.

Comment: Xdebug 2 is no longer supported though, so please upgrade! You also really don't want the profiler on when using code coverage. With Xdebug 2, desides the `-dzend_extension=` line, none of the xdebug settings have any influence on Xdebug's code coverage collection.